# Google Action leaves the mic open for a user command without a prompt

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created Google Assistant Conversation Action that sends user questions via webhook to IBM Watson. When I sent it for review, Google denied it for the following reason:

> Your Action leaves the mic open for a user command without a prompt, such as a greeting or an implicit or explicit question.

Example of a user conversation:

[image: Example of user conversation].

Google Action review team says the following:

> *I am happy to hear that  (mic opens)* - At this point, either prompt the user with further options or close the Action.

Do I need to send explicit or implicit questions every time, or would it be OK if I just sent a response with suggestions (quick replies) that can guide the user without asking them for something?

For example:

Action: I am happy to hear that  (mic opens)
Suggestions: "Tell me about your company"

Example of response with suggestion:

[image: Example of response with suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Google Home, a speaker where you cannot show suggestions. When your Action responds with "I'm glad to hear that." there is no further indication that it is listening or expecting a response. To the person using it, they don't know to say anything, and no reason to believe that the microphone is open.

In order to provide a better conversational experience, you should append a question to the end of each response. It can be something simple, like "What else do you want to talk about?" or you can make it more dynamic depending on the context.

Either way, you will need to provide auditory and visual clues that your Action wants to continue the conversation.